# How can I copy security fields between environments?

Tags: security, role-management, serialization

How can I copy security fields between environments? I can't use TDS serialization because there are too many changes that would be propagated.

Is it possible to simply only copy the security fields? And also choose which items to have their security fields copied out (and into another environment)?

Comment: Have you seen TDS `FieldLevelDeploy`? https://www.hhogdev.com/help/tds/fieldleveldeploy

Comment: Looks like a nice option but I don't think it deals with our scenario (this only applies to items with the setting Deploy Once).

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you have items which are deployed every time, it means you override whatever your content editor set. You can create new TDS project with the whole content tree, mark the items as `Deploy Once` and select `FieldLevelDeploy` option with `Security` field only. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not sure if I have enough time to check if this approach will work for me at work. Why don't you make an answer for this (with more detail?) and I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you need with TDS `FieldLevelDeploy`.

In general it allows you to deploy only selected fields of your items without overriding any other values.

You can create a new TDS project with the whole content tree, mark the items as `Deploy Once` and select `FieldLevelDeploy` option with `Security` field only.

You can read more about it:

- https://www.hhogdev.com/help/tds/fieldleveldeploy
- http://www.seanholmesby.com/team-development-for-sitecore-tds-part-2-advanced-usage/
- http://www.seanholmesby.com/team-development-for-sitecore-field-level-deployments/